# Python - Unable to delete files from folder using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am getting the error while deleting the files in folder.
Below is my code.

Part-1 of coding

```
pdf = FPDF()
sdir = "D:/IMAGES/"
w, h = 0, 0

for i in range(1, 25):
    fname = (sdir + str(i) + ".jpeg")
    if os.path.exists(fname):
        if i == 1:
            cover = Image.open(fname)
            w, h = cover.size
            pdf = FPDF(unit="pt", format=[w, h])
        image = fname
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.image(image, 0, 0, w, h)
    else:
        pdf.output(
            r"D:\DOCUMENTS\Google Drive\NewsPapers\Lokmat\Lokmat Mumbai Main "+str(d+A+Y)+".pdf", "F")
        pdf.close
```

Part-2 of coding

```
import os
dir_name = "D:/IMAGES/"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".jpeg"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))

        print("Done")
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Error I am getting is as below:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:/IMAGES/1.jpeg'
```

Comment: Have you closed all the processes that use the file before you tried to delete it?

Comment: @RulerOfJustice I am new to python and I dont know how to close all processes.

Comment: To put the question differently - have you got file "1.jpeg" opened?

Comment: @0buz No. Even I have restated the PC also. Still getting this error. I am updating my full code. Please see and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to write

```
cover.close()
```

After the line:

```
pdf = FPDF(unit="pt", format=[w, h])
```

Because of that, you still have an opened file and you cannot delete it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help :(

Comment: @AkshayPoklekar Well it works fine to me using python 3.8.2 , what errors are you getting when you use 0buz's or my answer?

Comment: I am also using python 3.82.  And getting the error:   PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:/IMAGES/1.jpeg'

Comment: @AkshayPoklekar Could you please update the code in the post so we will see the most 'fresh' code you're struggling with?

Comment: My problem is solved. Thanks for the help. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @AkshayPoklekar - you should accept this answer if you are happy with the input. After all it did state `cover.close()`, not `cover.close`.

Comment: @0buz Yes definitely :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
cover = Image.open(fname)
w, h = cover.size
pdf = FPDF(unit="pt", format=[w, h])
```

With:

```
with Image.open(fname) as cover:
    w, h = cover.size
    pdf = FPDF(unit="pt", format=[w, h])
```

Using `with` should help with situations where you may forget to close the file once you're done using it.

Comment: There are too many errors which I cant include in comments also :D

Answer (score 0):

**My problem is solved now :)**

Actually I used

```
cover.close()
```

insted of

```
cover.close
```

And I used this code before line

```
pdf.output(r"D:\DOCUMENTS\Google Drive\NewsPapers\Lokmat\Lokmat Mumbai Main "+str(d+A+Y)+".pdf", "F")
```